# Remove row with specific number in R

Tags: r

I want to remove row with the test "student2". However, I don't want to remove row like "student22", "student 23"... etc.
For example:

```
       Student.Code Values
1  canada.student12      2 
2   canada.student2      3 # remove
3  canada.student23      5 # keep
4       US.student2      6 # remove
5     US.student32       2
6    Aus.student87     645
7 Turkey.student25       4 #keep
```

I used the code `grepl("student2", example$Student.code, fixed = TRUE` but it also find (remove) the rows with like "student23"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `grepl("student2$", example$Student.Code)`

```
library(tidyverse)
example <- tibble::tribble(
             ~Student.Code, ~Values,
        "canada.student12",      2L,
         "canada.student2",      3L,
        "canada.student23",      5L,
             "US.student2",      6L,
            "US.student32",      2L,
           "Aus.student87",    645L,
        "Turkey.student25",      4L
        )

example$Student.Code
grepl("student2$", example$Student.Code)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

example %>% 
  filter(!grepl("student2$", Student.Code))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Student.Code     Values
  <chr>             <int>
1 canada.student12      2
2 canada.student23      5
3 US.student32          2
4 Aus.student87       645
5 Turkey.student25      4
```

Answer (score 3):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Student = c("canada.student12", "canada.student2", "canada.student23","US.student2", "US.student32", "Aus.student87", "Turkey.student25"),
  Value = c(2,3,5,6,2,654,5)
)
```

Solution: (in base R)

The idea is to use `grepl` to match those values where the number `2` occurs at the word boundary, that is, in regex, at `\\b`, and to exclude these strings with the negator `!`:

```
df[!grepl("student2\\b", df$Student),]
           Student Value
1 canada.student12     2
3 canada.student23     5
5     US.student32     2
6    Aus.student87   654
7 Turkey.student25     5
```

Alternatively, you can also go the opposite way and match those patterns that you want to keep:

```
df[grepl("student(?=\\d{2,})", df$Student, perl = T),]
```

Here, the idea is to use positive lookahead to match values with `student` **iff** they are followed immediately by **at least** two digits (`\\d{2,}`). (Note that when using lookahead or lookbehind you need to include `perl = T`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable with an exact value you want to remove, don't use grep or grepl.

```
example <- tibble::tribble(
             ~Student.Code, ~Values,
        "canada.student12",      2L,
         "canada.student2",      3L,
        "canada.student23",      5L,
             "US.student2",      6L,
            "US.student32",      2L,
           "Aus.student87",    645L,
        "Turkey.student25",      4L
        )

example <- example[example$Student.Code != "canada.student2",]
# or, in dplyr
example <- filter(example, Student.Code != "canada.student2")
# for multiple values
example <- filter(example, !(Student.Code %in% c("canada.student2", "US.student2")))
```

`fixed = TRUE` is not working because all it means is 'search for this exact string in the input strings', not 'only match this exact string (it must be the whole value)'